# Swift - Array - Remove a value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

It might be a simple question, but I am struggling to find a solution and I am blocked :(

I am working on a CollectionView which displays a list of avatars with their profile pictures. I am trying to add them on a Array when you select it and remove it when you deselect it.

This is my code and I have tried a lots of things but it doesn't work

**Function when a cell is selected**

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell2 = collectionV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SelectFriendCollectionViewCell
     let cell5 = self.collectionV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? SelectFriendCollectionViewCell
    let Friends_avatarname  = (cell5?.avatarUsername_Outlet.text! as? String!)!
    let Friends_UID = (cell5?.avatarUID_Outlet.text! as? String!)!


    let Friend = FriendsSelectArray(avatarUID: (Friends_UID as! String?)!, avatarname: (Friends_avatarname as! String?)!)
    self.FriendsSelect.append(Friend)
    print ("Friend added :\(Friend.avatarname)")

    }
```

**Function if cell deselected**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell2 = collectionV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SelectFriendCollectionViewCell
        let cell5 = self.collectionV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? SelectFriendCollectionViewCell


        let Friends_avatarname  = (cell5?.avatarUsername_Outlet.text! as? String!)!
        let Friends_UID = (cell5?.avatarUID_Outlet.text! as? String!)!
        var Friend = FriendsSelectArray(avatarUID: (Friends_UID as! String?)!, avatarname: (Friends_avatarname as! String?)!)

    }
```

**The class of the array**

```
class FriendsSelectArray{
    var avatarUID: String
    var avatarname: String


    init( avatarUID: String, avatarname: String){
        self.avatarUID = avatarUID
        self.avatarname = avatarname

    }
    func returnPostAsDictionary()->NSDictionary{
        let postDictionary: NSDictionary = ["avatarUID": avatarUID,
                                            "avatarname": avatarname]
        return postDictionary
    }
}
```

**And my starting class of CollectionView**

```
class SelectFriendViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionV: UICollectionView!

    var databaseRef: DatabaseReference!
    let cellIdentifier = "cell"
    var FriendsSelect : [FriendsSelectArray] = []
    var selectedCell = [IndexPath]()
```

It works when I add (When a cell is selected), but I can't manage to remove when you deselect the cell (the specific cell you deselected)

Please, can someone help me ?

A million thanks in advance,

Comment: Don't call `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:)` outside `collectionView(cellForRow:)` `UICollectionViewDatasource` method. Instead trust your model. Also `FriendsSelectArray` is not an array, that's a misleading name.

Comment: Hello Larme, thanks for your reply, i'll change it. But to remove my deselected cell in my array. How can i do it?

Comment: What is the data that is driving the actual collectionview?  Can you show that data structure and your `cellForItemAt`. You shouldn't need a specific structure to track selected items. You should just use the item that is already in your model. I would use a `Set` of those, or why not just use the selected items property of the collection view itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare the IDs of friend being removed from the list with IDs of all friends and remove the one needed from array and reload the collection view.

Please check out below code and comments in code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell2 = collectionV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SelectFriendCollectionViewCell
        let cell5 = self.collectionV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? SelectFriendCollectionViewCell


        let Friends_avatarname  = (cell5?.avatarUsername_Outlet.text! as? String!)!
        let Friends_UID = (cell5?.avatarUID_Outlet.text! as? String!)!
        var Friend = FriendsSelectArray(avatarUID: (Friends_UID as! String?)!, avatarname: (Friends_avatarname as! String?)!)

        // Pseudocode, remove friend from array logic.
        // Compare avatarUID of friend being removed and friends in the list.
        for x in (0..<FriendsSelect.count).reversed() {
             if(FriendsSelect[x].avatarUID == Friend.avatarUID) {
                 FriendsSelect.remove(at: x)
                 break
             }
        }

        // TODO: Reload array
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a property in the model so that it can tell you at any instant of time whether it is selected or not. example:

```
class FriendsSelectArray{
var avatarUID: String
var avatarname: String
var isSeleted: Bool = false


init( avatarUID: String, avatarname: String){
    self.avatarUID = avatarUID
    self.avatarname = avatarname

}
func returnPostAsDictionary()->NSDictionary{
    let postDictionary: NSDictionary = ["avatarUID": avatarUID,
                                        "avatarname": avatarname]
    return postDictionary
 }

}
```

then set `isSeleted = true` in the `didselect` item and `isSelected = false` in `itemDidDeselect` method. After this you can easily filter the selected items from the rest of the items in the `array`.